PUT request works with Postman but not with axios.put for Spring Security oAuth Resource Server backend
I have a vue frontend making requests to a spring boot backend configured as a resource server. I am having trouble configuring the backend in such a way that I can make requests from my frontend. The GET requests work from both Postman and my frontend, but any other request like PUT only works from Postman and returns a 401 if sent from my frontend. I suspected CORS, so I disabled it like so:
http
        .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
        .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/h2-console/**")).permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

If I try to disable CORS like so .cors(cors -> cors.disable) my GET requests from the frontend start to fail as well.
The PUT route is configured as follows in a @RestController class:
@PutMapping("/test")
void test() {
    System.out.println("called");
}

Adding the @CrossOrigin annotation did not work either.
The GET route is like this:
@GetMapping("/users")
List<RedditUser> all() {
    return repo.findAll();
}

The request is made with axios like this:
async saveCurrentChanges() {
            await axios.put("http://localhost:8080/api/test", { headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + getAuth().currentUser.accessToken }}).then((response) => {
                console.log("success");
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },

What really confuses me is why the requests from Postman get through but the PUT requests from my frontend do not.
I enabled logging for spring security in my application.context but all I get is this for blocked requests:
2024-06-27T14:57:44.286+02:00 DEBUG 10700 --- [xp-backend] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing PUT /api/test
2024-06-27T14:57:44.286+02:00 DEBUG 10700 --- [xp-backend] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext

and this for the successful GET requests:
2024-06-27T14:57:42.175+02:00 DEBUG 10700 --- [xp-backend] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /api/users
2024-06-27T14:57:42.460+02:00 DEBUG 10700 --- [xp-backend] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.o.s.r.a.JwtAuthenticationProvider  : Authenticated token
2024-06-27T14:57:42.460+02:00 DEBUG 10700 --- [xp-backend] [nio-8080-exec-2] .s.r.w.a.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to JwtAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt@abc94983, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]]
2024-06-27T14:57:42.462+02:00 DEBUG 10700 --- [xp-backend] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /api/users


It appears as if your PUT endpoint is using some other filter chain. Is that only security configuration which you got in your app?

Yes, that is the only security configuration I have in my app

Your frontend should not have access to tokens. Read that :https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2

CORS is a mechanism for allowing requests. CORS doesn't prevent requests.

I checked the successful requests vs. the unsuccessful ones and figured out that axios.put() was not sending the bearer token in the header. This is because axios.get() and axios.put() have different arguments:
Why is this axios put request not setting the headers peoperly
